# MySQL - Specific Table Replication

Tags: joomla, replication, mysql, virtuemart

Is there a script or a way for me to sync only certain tables from the master DB to all slave site DB's. They are all on the same server, but there are around 200 mysql db's and all of them must be kept in sync with main DB and replicate every hour or so... or alternatively is there a Joomla Component that can do the above with the Virtuemart Tables

Comment: Can you explain your problem a bit wider? You would need a 2nd MySQL instance to use replication. Why is space so limited? why not just specific MySQL access rights?

Answer (score 0):

If i'm understanding your question, you should check out the multisite component:

http://www.jms2win.com/